# VS Code extension - set config enum values programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I went through VS Code's documentation and Googled it but I cannot find is it possible to programmatically change the enums used in the config section of a custom extension. I need to change the enum as a whole - as an Array, not to a single - String - value.

For example, take this code (taken from VS Code's official docs)

```
 "gitMagic.blame.heatmap.location": {
    "type": "string",
    "default": "right",
    "enum": ["left", "middle", "right"] // this
 }
```

Is it possible to change the enum property runtime?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.So I replaced that behavior, now I'm using the Command Palette for that configuration method.

Comment: @SkyFlyer did you managed to find any solution after 2 years?
I've been wanting to add a runtime populated list of configuration enums, basically detect application versions installed on the system like llvm where users can install multiple versions - its not something that can be hardcoded into our extension

Comment: @JonnySoe, unfortunately no, as I answered before, I changed the behaviour of my extension, even though, I had the same use case as you... I needed to scan the host OS for apps, browsers in particular and then populate the enum with that list. I haven't tried doing it again since, I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Perhaps we can open a feature request ticket

Comment: I think the only way to do what you want is to programmatically edit and save the package.json.  Which can be done but it requires the user to reload vscode to have the changes become effective. So only a good workaround in unusual circumstances.

Comment: I've created a feature request here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187141

Comment: And the feature request has been closed as out of scope.

Comment: Thanks @jobor, man, unfortunately I saw on GH how it played out... Don't get it how it's out of scope but nothing we can do now. 

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
Try this:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
await vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().update("gitMagic.blame.heatmap.location", "right", vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global);
```

See more information [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration).

Comment: thank you for your response but unfortunately the provided method doesn't work, the update fails and the resulting Promise gets rejected because "enum" is not recognized as a property of the given configuration object.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought this is the content of settings.json file. I edited my answer. Please try now.

Comment: I have tried your code and every other possible combination and still no solution to this. I guess I'll need to change the behaviour of the feature and use the Command Pallete for extension config, instead of using the Settings. I'll keep the question open, maybe someone has a workaround for this. Thank you for you hard work, Yahavi. Much respect.